# How to make BottomNavigationView with NavigationUI avoid creating new fragment?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android

I tried to use `NavigationUI` to setup my `BottomNavigationView`. If I select any item then new fragment is created. But I need to show the same instance like in `ViewPager`. How to implement such thing?

Comment: did you found the solustion

Comment: Nope, I just used `ViewPager` with `FragmentPagerAdapter`